# Pasting image over lines in wx DC

Tags: python, image, wxpython, bitmap, buffer

I have the same code as wx Doodle pad in the wx demos.
I added a tool to paste images from the clipboard to the pad. 
using wx.DrawBitmap() function , but whenever i refresh the buffer .and call functions ( drawSavedLines and drawSavedBitmap)  it keeps putting bitmap above line no matter what I did 
even if I called draw bitmap first and then draw lines.

Is there anyway to put a line above the bitmap?

Please inform me if I miss anything.

Comment: put small code, which can be run without modification and demonstrates the problem

Comment: You might want to mention that the Doodle pad you're referring to is in the CustomDragAndDrop demo... I had to grep to find the class you were referring to.